# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.in28minutes.springboot:H2InMemoryDbDemo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am a beginner for spring boot. I followed the getting started guide. It was not successful. After that I import a project  from this link

http://www.springboottutorial.com/introduction-to-jpa-with-spring-boot-data-jpa.

It gives this error

"Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.in28minutes.springboot:H2InMemoryDbDemo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM"

I think i have missed some important configuration.

Thank you

Comment: it seems like maven is unable to connect and download spring-boot-starter-parent. this might happen if you are behind firewall or some connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding   relativePath tag under the parent tag, default location for relativepath is ... 
else define the proxy in settings.xml under .m2 folder location.

Comment: Where is the parent tag? How to define a proxy in settings. XML. Where is the m2 folder? Sorry,I am a beginner.

Comment: Where is the parent tag?                                                                       How to define a proxy in settings. XML. Where is the m2 folder? Sorry,I am a beginner.                                           Thank you

Comment: you can define the proxy for your maven in setting.xml you can refer https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: check if you enabled the anti-virus in your local machine. if yes, disable it for sometime and try again